# Distance between at most linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, homogeneous-equation

If we consider a linear function $f$, and an arbitrary positive constant $\lambda$ and points $x,y$, then we can find the distance from $f(\lambda x)$ to $f(\lambda y)$ as

$\| f(\lambda x) - f(\lambda y)\| = \| \lambda f(x) - \lambda f(y)\| = \lambda \| f(x) - f(y)\|$

If we now relax the linearity condition, to at most linear growth, i.e. $\|f(x)\| \leq c \|x\|$ and possibly also to satisfy the Lipschitz condition. Can we then do something similar to obtain, something like the following?

$\| f(\lambda x) - f(\lambda y)\| \leq \lambda^{\alpha} \| f(x) - f(y)\|$

Comment: I am not sure, but for me the condition $\| f(x) \| \leq c \|x\|$ does not seem to have anything to do with relaxing the linearity condition...

Comment: Well, if I am not mistaken linearity implies $\|f(x)\|\leq c\|x\|$. Then what I mean is that we now remove the linearity condition but keep $\|f(x)\|\leq c\|x\|$

Comment: Actually, the condition $\|f(x)\| \leq c \|x\|$ is equivalent to continuity of $f$ in the case that $f$ is linear. However, there exist linear unbounded functionals, so no, linearity does not imply $\|f(x)\| \leq c \|x\|$.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I forgot about functionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, without linearity there is no reason for $\| f(\lambda x) - f(\lambda y)\|$ to be controlled by $\| f(x) - f(y)\|$. For example, let
$$
f(x) = \max(0, |x|-1),\qquad x\in\mathbb{R} 
$$
This is a Lipschitz continuous function which satisfies $|f(x)|\le |x|$. Yet, there is no constant $C$ such that 
$$
|f(1)-f(2)| \le C|f(0.1)-f(0.2)|
$$
since the right hand side is zero while the left hand side is not.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was wondering, would it still be the case if I were to require some degree of smoothness? Like the existence of the first and possibly second derivatives.

Comment: A smooth function can have the same behavior as $f$ in this example: zero for awhile, then nonconstant.